# mysql select concat of one-to-many matches on left join

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

If have a table `roots` like:

```
id | root
```

and another `extensions` like

```
id | order | extensionpre | extensionval | extensionpost
```

How can I build a view like

```
id | root | group_concat(concat(extensionpre, extensionval, extensionpost))
```

Right now I'm trying:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  root,
  GROUP_CONCAT (concat(extensionpre, extensionval, extensionpost))
FROM roots AS rts LEFT JOIN extensions AS exts ON rts.id = exts.id
GROUP BY rts.root;
```

but sqlfiddle just says [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does not exist: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ef8/17

Comment: [Just remove the space between function and `(`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ef8/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a space between GROUP_CONCAT and (

Comment: you are absolutely right. What a dumb mistake! Thank you :-)

Comment: Definitely appreciated the link to SQLfiddle in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the space between `GROUP_CONCAT` and `(`